# Xamarin Forms default contructor not found for type on namespace.ShowOverlay

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement Overlay view from the [Link](https://xamarindevelopervietnam.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/how-to-show-ovelay-loading-in-xamarin-forms/). In android it is working fine but showing `System.MissingMethodException` on `UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");`

Upadated

```
System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type VenkysHRMS.iOS.ShowOverlay
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00066] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:171
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00009] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:153
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5639
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00039] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:201
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:134
  at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get[T] (Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fetchTarget) [0x00065] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\DependencyService.cs:35
  at VenkysHRMS.View.Login+<OnCreate>d__2.MoveNext () [0x0001b] in /Users/mac/Desktop/VenkysHRMS/VenkysHRMS/VenkysHRMS/View/Login.xaml.cs:33
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018
  at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at VenkysHRMS.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/mac/Desktop/VenkysHRMS/VenkysHRMS/VenkysHRMS.iOS/Main.cs:17
```

Comment: pls add details from exception

Comment: I notice that some of the code there has `namespace yournamespace`, but not all. Maybe the constructor and the place where it is called aren't in the same namespace, and the name needs to be quantified? Just a thought.

Comment: The dependency service can't create your "ShowOverlay" instance.  Your class (iOS Overlay class) must have an empty constructor definition in some cases  even if it's empty. ie: public IOSOverlay(){ }. You need it you have made another constructor in this class...

Comment: @S.L.Barth I have checked, it is in same namespace.

Comment: @Julien I have also added the empty constructor, in ShowOverlay